# coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryParamTag$InvalidDataException: Invalid data value [Column Name] exceeds maxlength setting 20

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have an email field.

```
 <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar"  maxlength="200" value="#structform.Email#">
```

On insertion, when I supply 20 or fewer characters as input, then insertion goes successful but when I supply more than 20 characters, then I get an exception.

> The cause of this output exception was that:
> coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryParamTag$InvalidDataException: Invalid data
> value nisar.ahmad@usefp.org exceeds maxlength setting 20..

Given that in the database (SQL server) the length of this field is 200.
and the following insert query successfully run

```
 Insert into table (Email) values ('ggggggggggggggggtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttggggggggggggggggg@gmail.com')
```

The input is greater than 20 charachetr.

Comment: There is no obvious error from what you have shown us. Are you sure it is throwing the error on that line of code?

Comment: Dear @Miguel-F, thank you for the comment. The actual error was not on that line rather it was on another line before this insert query. in the same function, I was having select query and then insert query.
The insert query was ok, but I mistakenly wrote maxlength="20"   in the select query ,in where clause for the Email column.
`select top 1  * from  Student
          where Email = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_longnvarchar" maxlength="20"  value="#structform.Email#">`

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be some where else in your code you have the maxlength set. Also check the **SQL where clauses.** Please also check the max length attribute in the cfqueryparam. You may have explicitly defined it in your code.